# Common practice for time format in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

What is the common (good) practice for the type of date+time columns in PostgreSQL? Timestamp WITH or WITHOUT time zone? Is it possible to output timestamps in all queries (selects) as a UTC string timestamp even if the column has a type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`?

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_timestamp_.28without_time_zone.29

Comment: Just use `timestamp with time zone` it will save you many headaches down the road.  The name withstanding `timestamp with time zone` does not store the timezone, it just stores the value at `UTC`. For more information see here [Date/time types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT) 8.5.1.3. Time Stamps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last question first: you can set the `timestamp` parameter to `UTC` or use `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`.

What data type to choose depends on how you want to handle time zones:

- if you don't care about time zones, use `timestamp without time zone`
- if you want to handle time zones in the application, use `timestamp without time zone` and store everything in UTC
- if you want to handle time zones in the database, use `timestamp with time zone` and set tge `timezone` parameter correctly